# Computing time complexity in C

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

I am facing some problem in how to compute the time complexity of my user define function. Big O notation is difficult for me to understand.

So here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_numbers_ascending(int number[], int count)
{

 int temp, i, j, k;
   
for (j = 0; j < count; ++j)
  
 {
      
for (k = j + 1; k < count; ++k)
     
 {
    
if (number[j] > number[k])
         
{
    
temp = number[j];
            
number[j] = number[k];
           
 number[k] = temp;
        
 }
     
 }
   
}
   
printf("Numbers in ascending order:\n");
   
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      
printf("%d\n", number[i]);

}

void main()

{
   
int i, count, number[20];
 
  
 printf("How many numbers you are gonna enter:");
   
scanf("%d", &count);
   
printf("\nEnter the numbers one by one:");
   
   
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      
scanf("%d", &number[i]);
 
   

sort_numbers_ascending(number, count);
}
```

I want to seek some help in computing time complexity in ( sort_numbrr_ascending(number, count); user defined function.

Comment: At least make the effort to format your code so it's even readable.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison sorting we consider the number of *comparisons*, sorting complicated objects this usually dominates.

Your outer loop *always* runs `count` times, your inner loop always runs *on average* ~`count / 2` times. Every iteration of the inner loop always does *one* comparison.

Hence you get best, worst and average case is `count * count / 2` which means all of them do *O(n²) **and Ω(n²) and θ(n²) comparisons*** (having n = the count parameter).

It is not the worst sorting algorithm imaginable if it works (I didn't care to test), but best comparison sorting algorithms achieve **O(n *log* n)** worst case. In practice a hybrid algorithm like Timsort would *always* outperform your code except for a handful of items.

Comment: @HeapOverflow indeed :D